# Cloud SQL: Instance update will not end

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a problem with my Cloud SQL Second Generation instance.

I used this instance for months without problems.
Every evening I stop the instance and every morning I perform a restart via Java, using "patch" API:

```
DatabaseInstance requestBody = new DatabaseInstance();
Settings settings = new Settings();
settings.setActivationPolicy(ALWAYS_POLICY);
requestBody.setSettings(settings);

SQLAdmin sqlAdminService = createSqlAdminService();
SQLAdmin.Instances.Patch request =
sqlAdminService.instances().patch(projectId, sql_instanceId, requestBody);

Operation response = request.execute();
```

Today after the usual restart operation, the instance results in an "Instance update" status that never ends.

All functions on the cloud console are disabled for the instance and I cant't perform any action.

These are the settings of my instance:

- Database version is MySQL 5.7
- Auto storage increase is enabled
- Automated backups are enabled
- Binary logging is disabled
- Located in europe-west1-c

How can I solve this situation?

Comment: I have the same problem creating new Cloud SQL instance (via cloud console). The instance creation is still pending after 2 hours!
It seems a Cloud SQL API problem but nothing is mentioned in the Google Cloud Status page.

Comment: After 6 hours of "pending requests" bot cloud SQL instances (the new instance created via cloud console and the old instance restarted via "patch" api) have been started. Both requests takes approximately 6 hours. Very strange. No Cloud SQL API problem is mentioned in the Google cloud status page.

Comment: I have just tried creating a new Cloud SQL instance and it took a couple of minutes. If you are still having issues or you encounter something similar in the future, I would advise opening a support ticket with Google Cloud Platform support so that a proper investigation could be carried out.